# Modifying a function passed as input

Tags: c++

I'm passing a function, f, to another function, SInf, but the 20+ times I call f in SInf, I call `f(1./x)/(x*x)`.

Is there a way to have another function, say `g(x)=f(1./x)/(x*x)`?  Though I guess not necessary to complete what I need to do, it would dramatically improve readability of the code.

I would rather not have a class or struct external to SInf, since I want it to be able to replace similar functions.

```
double SInf(double (*f)(double), int N, double aa, double bb, bool closed=true)
{

            struct functions{
             double fi(double x){return f(1./x)/(x*x);}
     };
     //bla bla lots of code
}
```

gives me

```
error: use of parameter from containing function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StilesCrisis is correct that lambdas are a good (if not the best) way of solving this. Here's what you can do:

```
//define a function g
auto g = [&f] (double _x) {return f(1./_x)/(_x*_x);};
//call g
g(x);
```

If you are unfamiliar with this syntax, I suggest you read [this article](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html) first. In particular, take a look at the "variable capture with lambdas" section.

Comment: I had to capture f with [&f] instead of []; I think because it was passed by reference to the function, but it worked after that change.

Answer (score 1):

You can do things like this easily with `std::function` and lambda functions. It will be difficult otherwise, as you'll have no way to pass additional arguments.

If you are writing an uncomplicated single-threaded app, you can still use regular function pointers and pass the extra state via globals, but that breaks down in a hurry when programs get complicated.